# VSTHost: How to configure "wave devices" without latency/delay problems?

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone, audio-recording

I have this physical connection:

```
               "line in"
Mike -------------------> Computer
```

And I was using Windows 7 with the following settings:

```
Playback devices --> Recording --> Line In --> Properties --> "Listen to this device" is UNCHECKED

Playback devices --> Playback --> Speakers --> Properties --> Line In: 100% (un-muted)
```

Those settings work awesome: I get 0 delay.
If I use the "**Listen to this device**" option instead, I get a delay of ~1000ms (horrible)

With that said, I wanted to put real time effects to the "Line-In", so I downloaded VSTHost and used this settings:

```
Windows settings:
-----------------

"Listen to this device" continues UNCHECKED

Playback devices --> Playback --> Speakers --> Properties --> Line In: now is muted
```

```
VSTHost settings:
-----------------

Devices > Wave devices > 
                          Input port: DS Line in
                          Output port: MME Microsoft Sound Mapper
```

But then I got the same delay as the one with "listen to this device" checked

**Question: What am I doing wrong? how can I achieve the same zero delay but with VSTHost instead of Windows?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end it helped me to use a low buffer (a small number of samples)

```
   Select wave devices
   -------------------------------------------
   Input port: (whatever that works)
   Output port: (whatever that works)
   Sample rate: default
   Buffer: THIS IS THE KEY PARAMETER!...
           the lower the number of samples (or higher b/s), the lower is the latency
```

Comment: which value did you end up using? Also: when using DS for output, the delay becomes extreme. Can you reproduce? Thanks!